# Run command with `system2(..., wait = FALSE)` in R and kill it later

Tags: r

Assume I want to start a local server from R, access it some times for calculations and kill it again at the end. So:

```
## start the server
system2("sleep", "100", wait = FALSE)
## do some work

# Here I want to kill the process started at the beginning
```

This should be cross platform, as it is part of a package (Mac, Linux, Windows, ...).

How can I achieve this in R?

---

## EDIT 1

The command I have to run is a java jar,

```
system2("java", "... plantuml.jar ...")
```

Comment: What do you want to do ? Do you just want some async computing in R like with the package future ?

Comment: No - it is a local PlantUML PicoWeb Server and I want to generate PlantUML Graphs (https://plantuml.com/picoweb)

Answer (score 1):

Use the `processx` package.

```r
proc <- processx::process$new("sleep", c("100"))
proc
# PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid 431792.

### ... pause ...

proc
# PROCESS 'sleep', running, pid 431792.
proc$kill()
# [1] TRUE

proc
# PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
proc$get_exit_status()
# [1] 2
```

The `finished` output is just an indication that the process has exited, not whether it was successful or erred. Use the exit status, where `0` indicates a good exit.

```r
proc <- processx::process$new("sleep", c("1"))
Sys.sleep(1)
proc
# PROCESS 'sleep', finished.
proc$get_exit_status()
# [1] 0
```

FYI, base R's `system` and `system2` work fine when you don't need to easily kill it and don't have any embedded spaces in the command or its arguments. `system2` appears like it should be better at embedded spaces (since it accepts a vector of arguments), but under the hood all it's doing is

```r
  command <- paste(c(shQuote(command), env, args), collapse = " ")
```

and then

```
  rval <- .Internal(system(command, flag, f, stdout, stderr, timeout))
```

which does nothing to protect the arguments.

---

You said "do some work", which suggests that you need to pass something to/from it periodically. `processx` does support writing to the standard input of the background process, as well as capturing its output. Its documentation at https://processx.r-lib.org/ is rich with great examples on this, including one-time calls for output or a callback function.

Comment: Sounds like a solution - although I would prefer something more lightweight.

Comment: Your choice: lightweight with `system2` and no ability to kill, feed input, or deal with embedded spaces, or `processx`. I know of no alternatives. (It's really not that heavy, though, it is only [importing](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/processx/index.html) packages `ps` and `R6`.)